# how to prevent document.write from overwriting my page

Tags: javascript, hex, shopify, decode

i have this code in my shopify theme which is over writing my document when i trigger it with settimeout function

```
var _0x1310=["\x3C\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x22","\x74\x69\x6D\x62\x65\x72\x6A\x73\x70\x61\x74\x68","\x70\x61\x74\x68","\x73\x68\x6F\x70\x74\x69\x6D\x69\x7A\x65\x64\x64\x65\x6D\x6F\x2E\x6D\x79\x73\x68\x6F\x70\x69\x66\x79\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x7C\x73\x68\x6F\x70\x74\x69\x6D\x69\x7A\x65\x64\x35\x2D\x30\x2E\x6D\x79\x73\x68\x6F\x70\x69\x66\x79\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x7C\x6F\x75\x74\x64\x6F\x6F\x72\x73\x61\x64\x76\x65\x6E\x74\x75\x72\x65\x72\x2E\x6D\x79\x73\x68\x6F\x70\x69\x66\x79\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D","\x2F\x63\x6F\x6C\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x73\x2F","\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x4F\x66","\x68\x72\x65\x66","\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E","\x2F\x70\x72\x6F\x64\x75\x63\x74\x73\x2F","\x61\x62\x6F\x72\x74","\x6F\x66\x66","\x66\x6F\x72\x6D\x5B\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x3D\x22\x2F\x63\x61\x72\x74\x2F\x61\x64\x64\x22\x5D","\x24","\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x69\x74","\x50\x6C\x65\x61\x73\x65\x20\x65\x6E\x74\x65\x72\x20\x79\x6F\x75\x72\x20\x76\x65\x72\x69\x66\x69\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x20\x70\x75\x72\x63\x68\x61\x73\x65\x20\x63\x6F\x64\x65\x20\x66\x6F\x72\x20\x66\x75\x6C\x6C\x20\x74\x68\x65\x6D\x65\x20\x66\x75\x6E\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x61\x6C\x69\x74\x79","\x61\x6C\x65\x72\x74","\x70\x72\x65\x76\x65\x6E\x74\x44\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6C\x74","\x73\x74\x6F\x70\x50\x72\x6F\x70\x61\x67\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E","\x6F\x6E","\x62\x6F\x64\x79","\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x73\x63\x72","\x70\x72\x6F\x64\x75\x63\x74\x5F\x6B\x65\x79","","\x62\x6C\x61\x6E\x6B","\x64\x6F\x6D\x61\x69\x6E","\x56\x65\x72\x69\x66\x69\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x20\x73\x74\x61\x72\x74\x20\x69\x73\x20\x62\x72\x6F\x6B\x65\x6E","\x64\x65\x62\x75\x67","\x63\x6F\x6E\x73\x6F\x6C\x65","\x5F\x73\x68\x6F\x70\x69\x66\x79\x5F\x70\x72","\x63\x6F\x6F\x6B\x69\x65","\x31\x38\x37\x34\x63\x33\x61\x65\x65\x34\x38\x64\x33\x34\x62\x65\x65\x36\x36\x31\x65\x38\x32\x30\x35\x38\x31\x32\x35\x32\x34\x32","\x74\x79\x70\x65","\x47\x45\x54","\x75\x72\x6C","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x73\x3A\x2F\x2F\x6D\x65\x6D\x62\x65\x72\x73\x2E\x73\x68\x6F\x70\x74\x69\x6D\x69\x7A\x65\x64\x2E\x6E\x65\x74\x2F\x61\x70\x69\x2F\x76\x61\x6C\x69\x64\x61\x74\x65\x2F","\x2E\x6A\x73\x6F\x6E","\x64\x61\x74\x61","\x76\x65\x72","\x35\x2E\x31\x2E\x30","\x64\x61\x74\x61\x54\x79\x70\x65","\x6A\x73\x6F\x6E","\x73\x75\x63\x63\x65\x73\x73","\x68\x61\x73\x4F\x77\x6E\x50\x72\x6F\x70\x65\x72\x74\x79","\x76\x61\x6C\x69\x64","\x44\x61\x74\x65","\x67\x65\x74\x54\x69\x6D\x65","\x73\x65\x74\x54\x69\x6D\x65","\x65\x78\x70\x69\x72\x65\x73","\x2F","\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x3D\x22\x64\x69\x73\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x3A\x62\x6C\x6F\x63\x6B\x20\x21\x69\x6D\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x61\x6E\x74\x3B\x70\x6F\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x3A\x66\x69\x78\x65\x64\x20\x21\x69\x6D\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x61\x6E\x74\x3B\x7A\x2D\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x3A\x39\x39\x39\x39\x39\x20\x21\x69\x6D\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x61\x6E\x74\x3B\x62\x6F\x74\x74\x6F\x6D\x3A\x30\x20\x21\x69\x6D\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x61\x6E\x74\x3B\x6C\x65\x66\x74\x3A\x30\x20\x21\x69\x6D\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x61\x6E\x74\x3B\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68\x3A\x31\x30\x30\x25\x20\x21\x69\x6D\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x61\x6E\x74\x3B\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x3A\x31\x30\x30\x70\x78\x20\x21\x69\x6D\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x61\x6E\x74\x3B\x6C\x69\x6E\x65\x2D\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x3A\x31\x30\x30\x70\x78\x20\x21\x69\x6D\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x61\x6E\x74\x3B\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2D\x61\x6C\x69\x67\x6E\x3A\x63\x65\x6E\x74\x65\x72\x20\x21\x69\x6D\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x61\x6E\x74\x3B\x62\x61\x63\x6B\x67\x72\x6F\x75\x6E\x64\x3A\x23\x66\x66\x30\x30\x30\x30\x20\x21\x69\x6D\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x61\x6E\x74\x3B\x63\x6F\x6C\x6F\x72\x3A\x23\x66\x66\x66\x20\x21\x69\x6D\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x61\x6E\x74\x3B\x6F\x70\x61\x63\x69\x74\x79\x3A\x31\x20\x21\x69\x6D\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x61\x6E\x74\x3B\x70\x6F\x69\x6E\x74\x65\x72\x2D\x65\x76\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x3A\x6E\x6F\x6E\x65\x3B\x22\x3E","\x6D\x65\x73\x73\x61\x67\x65","\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64","\x61\x6A\x61\x78","\x73\x65\x74\x54\x69\x6D\x65\x6F\x75\x74","\x69\x70\x74\x3E","\x77\x72\x69\x74\x65","\x64\x6F\x63\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74"];(function(){var _0x72cbx1=_0x1310[0]+ window[_0x1310[2]][_0x1310[1]],_0x72cbx2=_0x1310[3],_0x72cbx3;if(window[_0x1310[7]][_0x1310[6]][_0x1310[5]](_0x1310[4])===  -1&& window[_0x1310[7]][_0x1310[6]][_0x1310[5]](_0x1310[8])===  -1){_0x72cbx3= _0x1310[9]};function _0x72cbx4(){window[_0x1310[12]](_0x1310[11])[_0x1310[10]]();window[_0x1310[12]](_0x1310[19])[_0x1310[18]](_0x1310[13],_0x1310[11],function(_0x72cbx5){window[_0x1310[15]](_0x1310[14]);_0x72cbx5[_0x1310[16]]();_0x72cbx5[_0x1310[17]]();return false})}_0x72cbx1+= _0x1310[20];window[_0x1310[12]](function(){var _0x72cbx6=window[_0x1310[21]]&& window[_0x1310[21]]!== _0x1310[22]?window[_0x1310[21]]:_0x1310[23],_0x72cbx7=window[_0x1310[24]];if(_0x72cbx7!== _0x1310[22]&& _0x72cbx6=== _0x1310[23]&& _0x72cbx2[_0x1310[5]](_0x72cbx7)!=  -1){if(_0x72cbx3!= _0x1310[9]){window[_0x1310[27]][_0x1310[26]](_0x1310[25])};return}else {if($[_0x1310[29]](_0x1310[28])=== _0x1310[30]){return}};window[_0x1310[54]](function(){var _0x72cbx8={};_0x72cbx8[_0x1310[31]]= _0x1310[32];_0x72cbx8[_0x1310[33]]= _0x1310[34]+ _0x72cbx6+ _0x1310[35];_0x72cbx8[_0x1310[36]]= {};_0x72cbx8[_0x1310[36]][_0x1310[24]]= _0x72cbx7;_0x72cbx8[_0x1310[36]][_0x1310[37]]= _0x1310[38];_0x72cbx8[_0x1310[39]]= _0x1310[40];_0x72cbx8[_0x1310[41]]= function(_0x72cbx9){var _0x72cbxa={},_0x72cbxb;if(_0x72cbx9[_0x1310[42]](_0x1310[41])&& _0x72cbx9[_0x1310[42]](_0x1310[43])){if(_0x72cbx9[_0x1310[43]]){_0x72cbxb=  new window[_0x1310[44]]();_0x72cbxb[_0x1310[46]](_0x72cbxb[_0x1310[45]]()+ 86400000);_0x72cbxa[_0x1310[47]]= _0x72cbxb;_0x72cbxa[_0x1310[2]]= _0x1310[48];$[_0x1310[29]](_0x1310[28],_0x1310[30],_0x72cbxa)}else {window[_0x1310[12]](_0x1310[19])[_0x1310[52]](_0x1310[49]+ _0x72cbx9[_0x1310[50]]+ _0x1310[51]);_0x72cbx4()}}};if(_0x72cbx3!== _0x1310[9]|| (window[_0x1310[7]][_0x1310[6]][_0x1310[5]](_0x1310[4])!==  -1|| window[_0x1310[7]][_0x1310[6]][_0x1310[5]](_0x1310[8])!==  -1)){window[_0x1310[12]][_0x1310[53]](_0x72cbx8)}},3000)});window[_0x1310[57]][_0x1310[56]](_0x72cbx1+ _0x1310[55])})()
```

decoded using hex decoder

```
'var _0x1310=["<script src="","timberjspath","path","shoptimizeddemo.myshopify.com|shoptimized5-0.myshopify.com|outdoorsadventurer.myshopify.com","/collections/","indexOf","href","location","/products/","abort","off","form[action="/cart/add"]","$","submit","Please enter your verification purchase code for full theme functionality","alert","preventDefault","stopPropagation","on","body",""></scr","product_key","","blank","domain","Verification start is broken","debug","console","_shopify_pr","cookie","1874c3aee48d34bee661e82058125242","type","GET","url","https://members.shoptimized.net/api/validate/",".json","data","ver","5.1.0","dataType","json","success","hasOwnProperty","valid","Date","getTime","setTime","expires","/","<div style="display:block !important;position:fixed !important;z-index:99999 !important;bottom:0 !important;left:0 !important;width:100% !important;height:100px !important;line-height:100px !important;text-align:center !important;background:#ff0000 !important;color:#fff !important;opacity:1 !important;pointer-events:none;">","message","</div>","append","ajax","setTimeout","ipt>","write","document"];(function(){var _0x72cbx1=_0x1310[0]+ window[_0x1310[2]][_0x1310[1]],_0x72cbx2=_0x1310[3],_0x72cbx3;if(window[_0x1310[7]][_0x1310[6]][_0x1310[5]](_0x1310[4])===  -1&& window[_0x1310[7]][_0x1310[6]][_0x1310[5]](_0x1310[8])===  -1){_0x72cbx3= _0x1310[9]};function _0x72cbx4(){window[_0x1310[12]](_0x1310[11])[_0x1310[10]]();window[_0x1310[12]](_0x1310[19])[_0x1310[18]](_0x1310[13],_0x1310[11],function(_0x72cbx5){window[_0x1310[15]](_0x1310[14]);_0x72cbx5[_0x1310[16]]();_0x72cbx5[_0x1310[17]]();return false})}_0x72cbx1+= _0x1310[20];window[_0x1310[12]](function(){var _0x72cbx6=window[_0x1310[21]]&& window[_0x1310[21]]!== _0x1310[22]?window[_0x1310[21]]:_0x1310[23],_0x72cbx7=window[_0x1310[24]];if(_0x72cbx7!== _0x1310[22]&& _0x72cbx6=== _0x1310[23]&& _0x72cbx2[_0x1310[5]](_0x72cbx7)!=  -1){if(_0x72cbx3!= _0x1310[9]){window[_0x1310[27]][_0x1310[26]](_0x1310[25])};return}else {if($[_0x1310[29]](_0x1310[28])=== _0x1310[30]){return}};window[_0x1310[54]](function(){var _0x72cbx8={};_0x72cbx8[_0x1310[31]]= _0x1310[32];_0x72cbx8[_0x1310[33]]= _0x1310[34]+ _0x72cbx6+ _0x1310[35];_0x72cbx8[_0x1310[36]]= {};_0x72cbx8[_0x1310[36]][_0x1310[24]]= _0x72cbx7;_0x72cbx8[_0x1310[36]][_0x1310[37]]= _0x1310[38];_0x72cbx8[_0x1310[39]]= _0x1310[40];_0x72cbx8[_0x1310[41]]= function(_0x72cbx9){var _0x72cbxa={},_0x72cbxb;if(_0x72cbx9[_0x1310[42]](_0x1310[41])&& _0x72cbx9[_0x1310[42]](_0x1310[43])){if(_0x72cbx9[_0x1310[43]]){_0x72cbxb=  new window[_0x1310[44]]();_0x72cbxb[_0x1310[46]](_0x72cbxb[_0x1310[45]]()+ 86400000);_0x72cbxa[_0x1310[47]]= _0x72cbxb;_0x72cbxa[_0x1310[2]]= _0x1310[48];$[_0x1310[29]](_0x1310[28],_0x1310[30],_0x72cbxa)}else {window[_0x1310[12]](_0x1310[19])[_0x1310[52]](_0x1310[49]+ _0x72cbx9[_0x1310[50]]+ _0x1310[51]);_0x72cbx4()}}};if(_0x72cbx3!== _0x1310[9]|| (window[_0x1310[7]][_0x1310[6]][_0x1310[5]](_0x1310[4])!==  -1|| window[_0x1310[7]][_0x1310[6]][_0x1310[5]](_0x1310[8])!==  -1)){window[_0x1310[12]][_0x1310[53]](_0x72cbx8)}},3000)});window[_0x1310[57]][_0x1310[56]](_0x72cbx1+ _0x1310[55])})()\n'
```

using doucment.write but i dont know how to modify it

```
write","document
```

I tried some online tools to decode it but they didnt help me to completely decode it, from partial decoded part i saw document.write which i believe is over writing my entire page please excuse my eng

thank you

Comment: to disable document.write add in you js code : `document.write = function() {}`

Answer (score 0):

`document.write(...)` will always overwrite your document. Instead, you can use:

```
document.body.append(...);
```

which will do the same thing without overwriting. However, most of the time it makes more sense to use something like `document.getElementById("idOfElement").append(...)`